# Can't get visual studio to run projects on my browser

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, browser, output, vs-community-edition

I have worked within visual studio over 1,000 times. I'm trying to figure out how to attach a browser to my project so that I can view the solution.

Every time I try to run a file and click the 'play' button, there is no browser listed.

[picture of visual my visual studio attach button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeY6j.png)

How do I attach chrome or internet explorer and start my project?

Comment: What type of project is it? Obviously it doesn't make any sense to launch a web-browser for a WinForms project.

Comment: It's a visual studio web project

Comment: "visual studio web project" is not a project type. Is it a "Website" or a "Web Application"? And how was the project created? Is it under source-control? If it's a Web Application project do you have a history of the `.csproj`'s Debug settings history?

Comment: I've downloaded visual studio 2015 and i haven't done anything else. Everything is on default as shown in the picture. The particular project is a website.

Comment: it is not under source control. I just have an index file and i want to see it the browser